# How to make this curtain effect？

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I model the effect will be better, I feel that what I have done is too ugly.

Comment: Is cloth simulation an option? It would be simpler with cloth, I guess.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka-It should be more difficult to simulate with cloth.There are too few tutorials on fabrics.

Comment: It's actually not that difficult. Depends on how you like to do things. Check this tutorial, it may have something interesting to you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtwoLRLw9ow

Comment: what's the problem with what you've done? you just need to make your folds less sharp, hard to say how to do it without seeing your topology

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98315/how-to-create-a-cloth-stage-valance https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196739/how-can-i-get-this-curtain-to-open-and-close-realistically/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-make-a-curtain