# Top right part of pinned group is not scaled

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am doing this [Blender Guru tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3PIlhh9ruw&list=WL&index=1&t=400s) on Making a Curtain.He shows a method for closing the curtain from right to left. I cannot get that working.

I created a plane and subdivided that 100 times. Then I selected the top row of vertices and made that a Vertex Group. Then I clicked Cloth and made this Group the Pinned Group.

I then created a basis Shape Key and a Key1.Then I made the the top left vertex the pivot point and scaled all the vertices of the Vertex Group towards the selected vertex (50%). I set the value of key1 to 1.

Then I inserted a keyframe at 1 and a keyframe at 50 seconds. Then I played the animation.

Somehow the top right part (before scaling) is not part of the top left part (after scaling).

I don't understand what I did wrong.
You can download the file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/190mSuHTm0TIsnnubTX3x8S9TmWKe6fgP/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

In [How can I get this curtain to open and close realistically?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196739/how-can-i-get-this-curtain-to-open-and-close-realistically) there are three answers. Answer three uses the method I described (only with less vertices selected) and when I download the provided blend file it works in Blender 3.3 .....

Comment: AsI said when you asked this (now deleted) question before, that tutorial was done in Blender 2.83 and there's a comment from 'null' a few postings below the tutorial saying that it doesn't work in 2.93. I've not been able to find the "No Sync" setting he reckons you need to get it to work but I'm using Blender 3.3 and it could well have changed again.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know the tutorial, but i guess you want to move just the curtain?

Just insert a 0 at frame 0 for this value here, then press I.
Then go to frame 100 and enter value 1 and insert I again (or tap on the diamond behind it).

Then delete the bake and try again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The tutorial he's following is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3PIlhh9ruw) and I can confirm that it fails in Blender 3.3.

Comment: @JohnEason: i believe you that it fails. I didn't even look at it. But i looked at the blend file and this was very easy to fix, so i just hope it helps OP.

Comment: @Chris To be honest, perhaps I am doing things wrong but I cannot get it working.

Comment: I finally got it working. I used the Animation Workspace and selected the Shape Key Editor and there I inserted the keyframes like Chris said. And now it works like Blender Guru showed us.